# mhtml file with dropdown list blocked

Tags: mhtml

I am not very familiar with HTML and web development, so sorry for my wording.
I am wondering why I face such an weird situation for me. I want to save a webpage with some form where there are some dropdown lists to choose the answer. The purpose is to make a "screenshot" of that page, but to make possible to see what are the options in the dropdowns.
So my idea is to save a page as a single file .mhtml in Chrome. The questions look like this:

[image: How the question looks like on the web form]

But when I saved the page as .mhtml the file looks like this:

[image: Page after saving on local machine]

But the main purpose is to see the dropdown list in the file (so in this example list of months).
It nearly works in IE, but the outlook is different. And I am nearly sure that sometimes it doesn't work, but I have no idea why:

[image: The same file in IE]

Do you have any advice how to workaround that?

Comment: Are you're trying to embed a form in to an email for recipients to respond to directly from the email?

Comment: No, that is much simpler. After logging into system and building form, I am trying to open a "Form Preview" and save the preview as mhtml file.

Comment: I have found some solution for that, I used an extension to Chrome, SingleFile to download the entire site content as single html file.
But maybe there is another solution for that?